# select doesnt set it's selection in Bootstrap dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dialog with a bootstrap form elements in it.
Some of the elements are `<selcet>` type.

I would like to initialize all the select to the first option.
I use `$('select option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected');` which does the work of placing the `selected` attribute in all the first option of each select.

But when I bring the form up to view using `$('#insertPopup').modal('show');` none of the select elements have there first option selected, even though it has the attribute as mentioned.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Select an item</option>
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
</select>
```

I want that **item value 0** on the first select and **item value 1** on the second select be selected since they are both the first child of the parent select.

I've used :first-child, nth-child(1), all working in placing the `selected="selected"` in the line but the actual value does not appear to be displayed in the select text box.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `.val()` jQuery function:

```
$('select').val("123");
```

while the HTML is:

```
<select>
   <option>Select an option</option>
   <option value="123">The option will be selected</option>
</select>
```

---

If you just want to select the first option of the select you just need to replace `.attr()` with `.prop()`

```
$('select option:first-child').prop('selected', 'selected')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to be using as I may have different values on the first option. I just want to select the first option in each of the selects on the form.

Comment: @princeofchaos Then you will have to use `.prop`. See the edit.